# Creating process with arguments in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, process, openssl, command

Problem with doing process in Swift 3, It's not working, I click and nothing is happening.

```swift
let open = Process()
open.launchPath = "/usr/bin/openssl"
open.arguments = ["openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in \"" + existing.stringValue +
                 "\" -out \"" + new.stringValue + "/" + name.stringValue + "\""]
open.launch()
open.waitUntilExit()
```

How do I create a process with arguments in Swift?

Comment: You have to pass the arguments as separate array elements: `open2.arguments = ["enc", "-aes-256-cbc", "d", ...]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this function, you can pass the arguments as a string.

```
func shell(at: String, _ args: String) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = at
    task.arguments = ["-c", args]

    let pipeStandard = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipeStandard
    task.launch()

    let dataStandard = pipeStandard.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let outputStandard = String(data: dataStandard, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    if outputStandard.count > 0  {
        let lastIndexStandard = outputStandard.index(before: outputStandard.endIndex)
        print(String(outputStandard[outputStandard.startIndex ..< lastIndexStandard]))
    }
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Comment: `Task.launch` is deprecated, use `Task.run()`. `String(data: dataStandard, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!` is a force unwrap, use `guard let` to handle the error gracefully

see https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-an-external-program-using-process for a decent example of how to do this