# Why my arguments are being blocked when running a shell command?

Tags: swift, macos, shell, macos-catalina

I am looking to run a command on command line from my SWIFT app in MAC.

```
var resString = "open \(app.getLocation()) --args 25 40"
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", resString]
task.launch()
print (resString)
```

when I print the resString on console, I. get the following

```
open [path to app on my local drive] --args 25 40
```

which executes normally when I copy paste in the command line. but on the other side, the app is opened but arguments are being ignored.

I also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725745/12197482 still didn't work, the app is launched but the arguments don't get through

EDIT: Here's the funniest thing that's really frustrating, I created a small script that have a command, which contains

```
#! /bin/bash
open ./SimulatorDebug.app --args arg1 arg2
```

I ran it from terminal again, args are passed correctly with no issues. I tried to run at from my app and the same issue happened again, app run play BUT NO ARGS are being passed which is I find really weird.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/44/apple-s-new-utility-library-will-power-up-command-line-apps

Comment: The arguments are supposed to be passed as an array: `task.arguments = ["-c", "open", app.getLocation(), "--args", "25", "40"]`. And if the app is sandboxed you can't use `Process` anyway.

Comment: @vadian, Ok you were right, somehow args are passed when I deleted the sandbox, but I do actually need a sandbox since I am downloading a file from my local server. any workaround I can do?

Comment: Please read https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/. It's about AppleScript but it's the same pattern for shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/bin/sh` as `executableURL` instead:

```
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/sh")
```

That should do it.

You might also want to try using `task.run()` instead, and waiting for completion:

```
try task.run()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

I wrote System to make this much easier. Feel free to use it or copy/paste the code:
https://github.com/eneko/System/blob/master/Sources/System/System.swift#L107

#### Updated with additional info

Since you are trying to open a macOS app, there is no need to use `sh` or `bash`, you can invoke `open` directly.

To test this, I've written a sample macOS app in Xcode that all it does is display arguments on screen. Then, I proceeded to launch the app from a macOS Playground, as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code to launch the app with arguments:

```
let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/open")
process.arguments = [
    "/Applications/ArgumentTest/ArgumentTest.app",
    "-n",
    "--args",
    "Open",
    "From",
    "Playground"
]

try process.run()
```

`-n` is used to launch an instance of the app, even if the app is already running. Might not be needed in your case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still no luck! The app indeed starts but none of the arguments is passed! in a nutshell, my command that I execute from terminal is "open /Users/user/Downloads/test.app --args 25 40" and on the other app I log the args successfully, but when doing inside SWIFT with literally copy pasting the command the app starts but there's no args 

task.arguments = ["-c", "open /Users/user/Downloads/test.app --args 25 40"]

Comment: I almost went through all forums and followed many functions, all of them start the .app file but don't inject any args

Comment: also I imported the System package into my project and tried, still no luck! I believe it's a problem related to SWIFT

Comment: how to run with root priv?

Comment: @john elemans like I mentioned, if the actions isn't permitted it won't let the app run and block the arguments

Comment: @mahdi, I've updated my answer, see if it works now.